# Can't read and write file stream in the Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I've installed a VM virtual platform on my new Macbook Pro and then installed a Visual Studio 2015. But I just can't read or write any file stream in a c++ program.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: What happens?  What error message do you get?

Comment: I guess it a permission problem, maybe related to sandbox.

Comment: There is no error message. The VS just didn't read the file, and didn't write anything to the disc. Like, fout.open("write.txt"), and there will be no write.txt after the .exe is successfully finished, without any error massage.

Comment: @SHR what is sandbox, how to set the permission?

Comment: Could you also show us the code you're using?

Comment: The code is very simple: ofstream fout("write.txt"); fout << "testing."; fout.close();

Comment: I'm wondering whether this is related to the anti virus software Symantec. Is it possible that the AV has blocked the C++ to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be that the path name of my C++ working space contains Chinese characteristics "桌面" (desktop), and thus I cannot file out.

I then put my project file into Disc C, and made sure that there's no Chinese characteristics in the path name. Then it works!